# SCCM: Add a client to the sccm console

Tags: sccm

I have installed a SCCM system. My problem now is that I don't know how to integrate clients that are on the same network like the SCCM.
I have already created a location in the SCCM-Console and i have to integrate application software into the SCCM.
The Testclient already has a Windows 7 installed.
My question: How do I connect a client with the SCCM?

Answer (score 0):

It kind of seems like you are potentially asking a few different things here so I will give an answer to what I think you are asking and hopefully that helps
1. To add computers to sccm so they show up in your management console, you can either do it manually or via discovery. You can configure discovery in the administration tab. Normally you will want to discover computers from your AD setup.
2. To install the sccm client on the computers, you can either do it manually by running the software on the PC. Alternatively you can push out the client to computer by right clicking them and pushing out the client there.
3.To add software to sccm you can go to the software library tab and create either packages or applications.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup boundaries and boundary groups within SCCM based on subnet or AD sites.

Take a look at this example: http://shabaztech.com/sccm-2012-r2-client-installation/

If you have discovery turned on, you should be able to right-click a computer object within the SCCM console and install the client, assuming you have the proper accounts and firewall rules setup.